# How to make a flow run on a different thread than the one used for collection?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a flow that does CPU intensive work as shown below:

```
fun doWork():Flow<MyResult> = 
 flow{
  for(i in 1..100){
   //calculate()
   }  
   emit(MyResult())
 }
```

I collect from it inside a Fragment as shown below:

```
 viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            launch {
                viewModel.doWork().collect {
                    val result = it ?: return@collect
                    // Preview result
                }
            }
        }
```

But, since I am collecting using the main thread, the flow body runs on the main thread which is not the best thing to do.

How can I make the flow execute on a different thread?

Answer (score 1):

In case you intend to do heavy calculations inside a flow it is recommended to move it to the default dispatcher like so,

```
  flow{
     //CPU intensive work
  }.flowOn(your chosen dispatcher)
```

Libraries like the Room database and retrofit for networking handle the correct threading under the hood for you, so you do not have to worry about using `.flowOn`

Using `withContext()` inside a flow will not work for you.

This [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html) is also very useful if you want to know more about asynchronous Flow.